# App rejection issue when submit to Facebook for review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-friends

I have integrated Facebook SDK for the first time. I have submitted it to Facebook for review and its got rejected. Now let me tell you the steps I followed and the issue where I am going through.

1. Created an app with Facebook email, public_profile permission and went live (as its not required the review as per the document and its working fine)
2. Now due to change (enhancement) in the business requirement, I had to add user_friends permission also in the existing app. I have gone through many links and read about the [facebook app review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review) and [Facebook test apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/) I have created a test app for the actual app and integrated the user_friends permission (as it works for test app)
3. Since the previous live app was with general permission *(email, public_profile)* I have not submitted this for review. So, this time I have submitted the test app for review and it got rejected (fb reviewer message 
   -- unable to login)

***Question:***

But it's still working. I am able to login properly. **Cant understand what and where the problem is?** I have googled for solution and found that we need to submit actual app for review. But how, the actual app is already live without ***user_friends*** permission, so in that case it will again get rejected.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not submit test apps, you need to submit the actual app you want to use the permission with. If your app is already live, then you need to find a way to make it testable for the reviewers, without disrupting the functionality for existing users. Like provide them with an address with an extra parameter added, and make it only ask for the un-reviewed permission when that is set, something like that.

Comment: do you think this is the correct way, if yes, then why test app concept is there. Is there any way where they do change the app id from actual app to test app? If yes, then this case may be valid.

Comment: No, there is currently no way to switch app ids between a real app and a test app.